# How to find-out Bulk text from a list of URL using any script

Tags: javascript, excel, vba

I have a list of URLs in a Excel sheet, I want to find out Version of Pages and to list out on the excel sheet from B2:B144.

[image]

Please suggest how to do this, some ideas i am thinking below.

```
Sub CheckPageData()

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim IntExp As Object

    Set IntExp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IntExp.Visible = True

    For Each cell In Range("A2:A144")
        'Here A2 is cell Address where we have stored urls which we need to test.

        If Left(cell.Value, 4) = "http" Then


        End If
    Next cell

    IntExp.Quit
    Set IntExp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: then navigate to page using cell value ........ then ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not too familiar with the HTMLDocument Object so this is more of a partial answer.

I use MSXML's XMLHTTP object to get the html document as a string from the website. Then I load the string into an HTMLDocument Object. Once in the HTMLDocument Object, you can use the `.getElementsByTagName` function to create a list of any matching items. If the list isn't empty, it returns the text contained within the first item on the list.

```vb
Sub Example()
    Debug.Print GetElementValue("version", "https://pulseinfomatics.com/vba-scraping-website-msxml-htmldocument/")
End Sub

Function GetElementValue(ElementName As String, FromURL As String) As String
                
    Dim http As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    http.Open "GET", FromURL, False
    http.Send
    
    If http.Status <> "200" Or http.responsetext = "" Then Exit Function 'Connection Failed / No response
    
    Dim htmlDoc As HTMLDocument
    Set htmlDoc = New HTMLDocument
    htmlDoc.Body.innerHTML = http.responsetext
    'htmlDoc.defaultView.Window.Close
    
    Dim searchresults As Object
    Set searchresults = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(ElementName)
    
    If searchresults.Length = 0 Then Exit Function 'No elements found with that tag
    GetElementValue = searchresults(0).innerText
    
    htmlDoc.Close
End Function
```

Problems: It tries to open IE on the line `htmlDoc.Body.innerHTML = http.responsetext` and I don't know how to make it not do that. I tried `htmlDoc.defaultView.Window.Close` but it opens a confirmation box asking if you want to close the window.

Note: Add the references to your project to gain access to these objects.

1. Microsoft XML, v6.0
2. Microsoft HTML Object Library